# Outputting sine waves on xy plots — stuck on certain parts

Tags: vb.net

Please help I want to know exactly what is going on in this code for a questions and answers exam tomorrow.

I don't need any help with writing the code because that would be cheating. I made a tiny few mistakes please forgive me I rectified most of theses I don't need help with the mistakes just with the  comments and understanding mostly how it works.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
   MSComm1.Output = "83" + Chr$(13)
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
  MSC1.PortOpen = True
  Average_val = 0
  minimum_val = 255
  maximum_val = 0
  Screenshotofsinewave.Left = 0
  Screenshotofsinewave.Channel(0).TraceVisible = True
  Screenshotofsinewave.Channel(0).MarkersVisible = True
  sumofall_val = 0
  Screenshotofsinewave.TitleVisible = False
  Screenshotofsinewave.Top = 0
  Screenshotofrectifiedsinewave.TitleVisible = False
  Screenshotofrectifiedsinewave.Channel(0).TraceVisible = True
  Screenshotofrectifiedsinewave.Channel(0).MarkersVisible = True
  Screenshotofrectifiedsinewave.Top = 0
  Screenshotofrectifiedsinewave.Left = 0
  Screenshotoflevelshiftedsinewave.Top = 0
  Screenshotoflevelshiftedsinewave.Left = 0
  Screenshotoflevelshiftedsinewave.TitleVisible = False
  Screenshotoflevelshiftedsinewave.Channel(0).TraceVisible = True
  Screenshotoflevelshiftedsinewave.Channel(0).MarkersVisible = True
End Sub

Private Sub MSC1_OnComm()
  Dim number_val
  Dim number1_val
  Dim Average_val
  Dim com1_val
  p = 0
  q = 0
  r = 0
  s = 0
  t = 0
  Dim Xarr(50) As Single
  Dim Yarr(50) As Single
  Dim number2_val
  Dim number3_val
  Dim Snapshotofsinewave

  Dim string1_out As String
  Dim string1_in As String

  Dim counter As Single
  Dim sample_rate As Integer

  Select Case MSC1.CommEvent 
    Case comEvReceive
      minimum_val = 255
      string1_in = MSC1.Input
      Screenshotofsinewave.Channel(0).Clear
      Screenshotofrectifiedsinewave.Channel(0).Clear
      Screenshotoflevelshiftedsinewave.Channel(0).Clear
      counter = 0
      comm_count = comm_count + 1
      For sample_rate = 1 To 150 Step 3
        string1_out = Mid(string1_in, sample_rate, 3)
        counter = counter + 1
        number_val = Val(string1_out)
        Xarr(counter) = counter
        Yarr(counter) = number_val
        Screenshotofsinewave.Channel(0).AddXY counter, number_val
        If number_val > maximum_val Then
          maximum_val = number_val
          MaxVoltage.Value = maximum_val
        End If
        If number_val < minimum_val Then
          minimum_val = number_val
          MinVoltage.Value = number_val
        End If
        sumofall_val = number_val + sumofall_val
        Average_value = sumofall_val / 50
        AverageVoltage.Value = Average_value
      Next sample_rate

      counter = 0
      sumofall_val = 0
      For sample_rate = 1 To 150 Step 3
        string1_out = Mid(string1_in, sample_rate, 3)
        counter = counter + 1
        number_val = Val(string1_out)
        number_val = number1_val - Average_value
        number_val = numer_val
        If num_val1 < 0 Then
          number_val = number_val * -1
        End If
        Xarr(counter) = counter
        Yarr(counter) = number1_val
        Screenshotofrectifiedsinewave.Channel(0).AddXY counter, number1_val
      Next sample_rate

      counter = 0
      For sample_rate = 1 To 150 Step 3
        string1_out = Mid(string1_in, sample_rate, 3)
        Count = Count + 1
        number_val = Val(string1_out)
        number2_val = number_val + Average_value
        Xarr(Count) = counter
        Yarr(Count) = number2_val
        LevelShifted.Channel(0).AddXY Count, number_val2
        sumofall_val = number_val + sumofall_val
      Next sample_rate

      counter = com1_val
      Snapshotofsinewave.Value = com1_val
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub Frame4_DragDrop(Source As Control, X As Single, Y As Single)

End Sub

Private Sub Uploaddata_Click()
  If GXSwitch1.SwitchOn = True Then
    led1.LampOn = True
    p = 8
  Else
    led1.LampOn = False
    p = 0
  End If
  If GXSwitch2.SwitchOn = True Then
    led2.LampOn = True
    q = 4
  Else
    led2.LampOn = False
    q = 0
  End If
  If GXSwitch3.SwitchOn = True Then
    led3.LampOn = True
    r = 4
  Else
    led3.LampOn = False
    r = 0
  End If
  If GXSwitch4.SwitchOn = True Then
    led4.LampOn = True
    s = 8
  Else
    led4.LampOn = False
    s = 0
  End If
  t = p + q + r + s
  If t = 0 Then
    MSC1.Output = "0" + Chr$(13)
  End If
  If t = 1 Then
    MSC1.Output = "1" + Chr$(13)
  End If
  If t = 2 Then
    MSC1.Output = "2" + Chr$(13)
  End If
  If t = 3 Then
    MSC1.Output = "3" + Chr$(13)
  End If
  If t = 4 Then
    MSC1.Output = "4" + Chr$(13)
  End If
  If t = 5 Then
    MSC1.Output = "5" + Chr$(13)
  End If
  If t = 6 Then
    MSC1.Output = "6" + Chr$(13)
  End If
  If t = 7 Then
    MSC1.Output = "7" + Chr$(13)
  End If
  If t = 8 Then
    MSC1.Output = "8" + Chr$(13)
  End If
  If t = 9 Then
    MSC1.Output = "9" + Chr$(13)
  End If
  If t = 10 Then
    MSC1.Output = "10" + Chr$(13)
  End If
  If t = 11 Then
    MSC1.Output = "11" + Chr$(13)
  End If
  If t = 12 Then
    MSC1.Output = "12" + Chr$(13)
  End If
  If t = 13 Then
    MSC1.Output = "13" + Chr$(13)
  End If
  If t = 14 Then
    MSC1.Output = "14" + Chr$(13)
  End If
  If t = 15 Then
    MSC1.Output = "15" + Chr$(13)
  End If                            
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think you have enough "if" statements.

Comment: Take a look at [anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx)

Comment: how/why would an average value ever be a string?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on several factors...

```
Dim average_val, x As Decimal ' decimal
Dim average_val = 3.2D ' decimal if Option Infer On
Dim average_val = 3.2D ' object with boxed decimal if Option Infer Off
Dim average_val ' Object if Option Strict Off, otherwise an error
```